# Android Kitkat 4.4.2 ImageView setBackgroundResource not working?

Tags: android, imageview, background-image

Today i came through a strange problem that ImageView.setBackgroundResource() is not working in android kitkat 4.4.2, but it is working fine in other versions. This is how i am using it:

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageview_border);
```

This is the drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke
        android:width="6dip"
        android:color="@color/brown" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="6dip"
        android:left="6dip"
        android:right="6dip"
        android:top="6dip" />

</shape>
```

I have searched a lot but did not able to solve the problem. I don't know whether someone else is facing this problem in 4.4.2 except me or not. Please help me.

Comment: Did you try with `imageView.setBackground(R.drawable.imageview_border);`???

Comment: @SweetWisherツ same result. Its not working at all.

Comment: @SweetWisherツ .setBackground accepts a drawable not a resource id.

Comment: then he can try with `imageView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imageview_border));` @TheLittleNaruto.

Comment: then you should reply him with proper guidance :)  @SweetWisherツ

Comment: I thought we will get the way..I just wanted to tell him the method to use :P @user1726619 did you try the same way ??

Comment: @user1726619 I tried your code in my Moto G (4.4.2) and it's working fine, you can test the apk too in your device get it from [**Here**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qvfp4vlq7gga9cz/AndroidTest.apk)

Comment: Why does your apk require write external storage and internet permission to demonstrate this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageview_border);
```

Instead of this

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageview_border);
```

It will work.